# Default Cubes: Webs? Easy Enough! (Blender Tutorial)

Tags: procedural

In the tutorial *"WEBS? Easy Enough!"* by DefaultCube, he uses the "poke faces" method on the inside of a filled circle to create "web edges" connected at a center point. However, if you try to do this with a triangle, it only makes 3 "web" edges, because there are only 3 vertices to connect to.

However in the intro to the video, he shows a triangle with many more "Webs". How can I do this with a triangle?

[image: WebTri]

Comment: Hello, and welcome. Please add [more information](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/192302/edit) to your question. (No one knows what tutorial you are talking about) and have a look [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how this site works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For those wondering, this question is about the Video -

["WEBS? Easy Enough! (Blender Tutorial)" by DefaultCube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yWgt57atOg)

To get what you're looking for, select each edge of the triangle individually. Right click and select subdivide. You can increase the number of subdivisions in the lower corner box to get the number of vertices per side you want. DO this for all edges.

[image: Poketri]

Now select the whole mesh and select "poke faces" as is done in the video.

[image: Poketri2]

An alternative way of getting the same result (but is more "visible" as to what's going on along the way) is to start with your triangle and inset it.

[image: Tri1]

Now select sets of inner and outer edges (in pairs) and right click and select subdivide.

[image: Tri2]

You can increase the number of subdivisions in the box in the corner to get the number of sides you want.

[image: Tri3]

Do this for all pairs of sides.

[image: Tri4]

You can now select the inner face, hit <kbd>M</kbd> and select "at center"

[image: Tri5]

You can then select the center point and move it like in the video,

[image: Tri6]

Comment: Thank you so much for this man, that's an incredibly detailed answer. I really appreciate it.